# Function which is not in $L^2(R)$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $exp^{x^3}$ is not in $L^2(R)$ .Can someone help me please  ?
I don't know how to deal with this question.

Comment: Is $exp^{x^3}$ instead of $e^{x^3}$?

Comment: You'll need to know the integral of $f = e^{x^{3}}$. Alternatively, look at the plot of $f$ and see that it is monotonic increasing in $x$ and that $f > 0,  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ to see that the integral is unbounded.

Comment: we have $f'(x)=3x^2f(x)$ which is positive hence f is increasing in R .but how does that imply  that the integral is unbounded?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)\ge1$ if $x\ge0$. Then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2\,dx\ge\int_0^\infty 1\,dx=\infty.
$$

Comment: That's it. So simple.

Comment: and how we prove that if $x \in R^n$ and we work in $L^2(R^n)$

Comment: is it true to write  $f(x)\ge 1$ if $|x| \ge 0 $ then $\int_{R^n} |f(x)|^2\,dx\ge\int_{|x|\ge 0} 1\,dx=\infty$.

Comment: First of all, what is $e^{x^3}$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?